# My final result doesn't match the intended result for a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CHP4Ex
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("enter a n: ");
          int n = scan.nextInt();
          int i=0;
          int sum=0;
          while ((i%2 == 0 && i<=n))
          {
             sum = sum + i;
             i++;
          }
          System.out.println(sum);
     }
}
```

I'd like to:
Write a loop that computes the sum of all even numbers between 2 and 100 (inclusive).

However, anything I type in gives an answer of 0 instead of the intended result.

Comment: `while ((i%2 == 0 && i<=n))` stops at i==1 when sum is 0. You should leave only `i<=n` here and put a condition with `i%2==0` on increasing the sum.

Comment: Okay makes sense. i++ does keep the iteration going? I want the iteration to end when i<= n, not when the while loop reads false exactly.

Comment: @AdamStaples Thats what a while loop does, loops as long as the condition is true, you want to seperate your loop from your condition

Comment: use a if statement to check the condition, otherwise you are exiting from the loop if you get a odd number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several answers have pointed out that the even test exits the first time. The problem is that that two tests are not related. You want to exit when you've reached your limit. And you want to add when it's even. Separate the two tests

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CHP4Ex
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("enter a n: ");
          int n = scan.nextInt();
          int i=0;
          int sum=0;
          while (i<=n)
          {
              if (i%2 == 0)
              {
                  sum = sum + i;
              }
              i++;
          }
          System.out.println(sum);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop stops at **i = 1**, hence your result:

```
while ((i%2 == 0 && i<=n)) { //when i = 1, i%2!=0 -> stop
  sum = sum + i;
  i++;
}
```

You should use a for loop :

```
 for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2) {
   sum+=i;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
       while (i <= n)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

for loop,

```
        for (int j = i; j <= n; j += 2)
        {
            sum = sum + j;
        }
```

Comment: Perfect. 
From the different answers I like this method and the For loop method. This actually puts my thoughts exactly into the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition in the while loop is wrong:

```
while ((i%2 == 0 && i<=n)) ...
```

It just adds 0 to `sum` and then exits the `while` loop. Indeed at the second iteration:

```
i % 2 == 0 // i = 1; 1 % 2 == 0 is FALSE
```

Use this instead:

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i+=2) {
    sum += i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop has the problem. It comes out as soon as i becomes 1

Try this

```
while(i<=n) {
  if(i%2==0)
    sum+=i;
  i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time i is odd (at 1) the loop will exit

```
while ((i%2 == 0 && i<=n)) <<- i%2 == 0 causing problems
```

hence the answer is always zero.

You want the range of i in the loop, but the condition of evenness in an if statement; so

```
      while (i<=n)
      {
         if (i%2 == 0){
             sum = sum + i;
         }
         i++;
      }
```

Although of course a for loop would be more appropriate for running through a range

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     if (i%2 == 0){
          sum = sum + i;
     }
}
```

Of course this is somewhat inefficent, better yet just skip all the odd numbers

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2){
     sum = sum + i;
}
```

But as you could do this directly by formula I'm assuming this may be extended to a more complex condition

Answer (score 0):

*anything I type in gives an answer of 0 instead of the intended result.* 
because loop ends at `i=1`

Answer (score 0):

Split the condition in the `while` loop. Because your use of the `&&` operator, both statements need to be true all the time. With `i=1`, the first condition fails and the loop is aborted.

Put only the `i<=n` in the loop condition, then place `if(i%2)` around the addition of `Sum`.

```
while (i<=n)
{
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exit clause from wile loop is wrong. On second iteration **i** will be 1, and **i%2 == 0** will give false. There is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake! You have `&&` in loop! So the first condition fails for `i=1`, hence you break out of loop!